# FastAPI with Pydantic validator on composition of other models

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

I have some Pydantic objects where I was trying to use the `__init__` to update fields (e.g. time) or send events, but the events were getting called every time I returned a Pydantic object from a FastAPI handlers.

**simplified example**

```py
class OtherModel(BaseModel):
    value: int


class SomeModel(BaseModel):
    other: OtherModel

    @validator('other', pre=True, always=True)
    def are_items_in_order(cls, other):
        cur_val = 0
        if cur_val > other.value:
            raise ValueError('out of order')
        return other


def some_function() -> SomeModel:
    val1 = OtherModel(value=1)
    something = SomeModel(other=val1)
    print(something)
    return something


@app.get("/test", response_model=SomeModel)
async def exec_test():
    something = some_function()
    print(something)
    return something
```

The output from the first prints looks good

```
other=OtherModel(value=1)
other=OtherModel(value=1)
```

But then I get an error from Pydantic because it is trying to execute my validator, but now with a `dict` instead of the object

```
if cur_val > other.value:
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'value'
```

How to handle or avoid this failure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you wish to validate each list value on its own (compare it to 0), an [each_item=True validator](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/validators/#pre-and-per-item-validators) should work for you

Comment: I just simplified the example to remove the `List`.  The failure has to do with the model vs dict representation.  When initialized the first time the value is a model, but when returned via FastAPI it is only a `dict`, but calls the same validator.

Comment: I think it's because you're using "pre=True" which results with "other"  field not populated correctly. Can you try removing it and see if it works?

Comment: Removing `pre=True` does get rid of the failure.  I do have other questions, but I'll start a new topic.